# SQL Query for finding specific row in posgresql server

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables [image: tables] respectively `department_location` and `project`

I would like to find any projects running at a different location than the department location.

The resulting should be like this:[image: like this]

The code that I've implemented :

```
SELECT pro.pnumber,pro.pname,pro.plocation,dept.dlocation
FROM project AS pro,dept_location AS dept
WHERE pro.plocation != dept.dlocation AND pro.dnum = dept.dnumber
GROUP BY pro.pnumber,dept.dlocation
```

What am I missing?

Edit: Here is my[.sql file](https://gofile.io/?c=icR4qG)

Comment: You don’t need the group-by clause

Comment: You appear to be storing both foreign key and its corresponding *location* value in second table. Only foreign keys should be stored and avoid any duplicate, redundant related data that can be retrieved through `join` query.

Comment: Also, avoid old-style, implicit join with comma-separated tables with `where`. Instead, use the [explicit join](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1018822/1422451) (current standard of over 25 years).

Comment: For this sample data what is your exact expected results?

Comment: This is a postgresql question. Why tag with mysql?

Answer (score 0):

I see, here is a corrected version:

```
SELECT pro.pnumber,pro.pname,pro.plocation,dept.dlocation
FROM dept_location AS dept left join project AS pro on 
pro.plocation = dept.dlocation AND pro.dnum = dept.dnumber
Where pro.plocation is null
```

Comment: it totally gives irrelevant result which I cannot solve it how. Could you try it [my .sql file](https://gofile.io/?c=icR4qG)

Comment: Would you believe me if I say it doesn't give any result. @zip

Comment: Do you mind posting the sample in text so we can run tests with data Slim?

Comment: Here is my [sql](https://gofile.io/?c=ja377k) table. Could you download it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct pname, plocation, dlocation
FROM project INNER JOIN department_location ON project.dnum=department_location.dnumber 
WHERE plocation <> dlocation;
```

First join the 2 tables using an inner join, then you will get a single table with all the info for every project, then keep only the rows where the project location differs from the department location.

Comment: I shaped into according to my tables of your code but it doesn't work

SELECT distinct pro.pname, pro.plocation, dept.dlocation
FROM project as pro INNER JOIN dept_location as dept ON pro.plocation=dept.dlocation
WHERE plocation <> dlocation;

Comment: see the corrected answer, the inner join creates a new table so you can't refer to columns as pro.pname you need to put just pname, plocation and dlocation

Answer (score 0):

You can group by project and use `string_agg()` to return the results as a comma separated list:

```
SELECT 
  p.pnumber, p.pname, p.plocation, 
  string_agg(CASE WHEN d.dlocation <> p.plocation THEN d.dlocation END, ',') deptlocations
FROM project AS p INNER JOIN dept_location AS d
ON p.dnum = d.dnumber 
GROUP BY p.pnumber, p.pname, p.plocation
HAVING SUM((p.plocation <> d.dlocation)::int) > 0
ORDER BY p.pnumber
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=e62358ba3af729a6f232dcb97d20a560).
Results:

```
> pnumber | pname          | plocation | deptlocations     
> ------: | :------------- | :-------- | :-----------------
>       1 | ProductX       | Bellaire  | Sugarland,Houston 
>       2 | ProductY       | Sugarland | Bellaire,Houston  
>       3 | ProductZ       | Houston   | Bellaire,Sugarland
>      20 | Reorganization | Houston   | Ankara            
>      99 | Geomatics      | Ankara    | Houston
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution is:

```
SELECT p.pnumber, p.pname, p.plocation, d.dlocation
FROM project p JOIN
     dept_location d
     ON p.dnum = d.dnumber  AND
        p.plocation <> d.dlocation;
```

Functionally, this is your query without the `GROUP BY`  However, you should learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.